# InvalidOperationException "get_MetadataToken() cannot be used on the current platform" when creating tables

Tags: win-universal-app, entity-framework-core

This is an interesting problem for me. On my work machine, my code works perfectly fine, but on my home machine when starting with a new `sqlite` file I get an `InvalidOperationException` when `db.Database.Migrate()` is called.

According to *Windows Update*, both machines are up to date.

Visual Studio 2015 also shows as up to date on both machines.

I'm running EF7 rc1-final

The stacktrace isn't exactly deep:

```
   System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The API 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo.get_MetadataToken()' cannot be used on the current platform. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273 for more information.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
  InnerException:
```

The provided link just goes to the MSDN main page. I'd personally prefer a `404`.

There's [Issue 190](https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/issues/190), but I don't see why it would only be a problem on one of my machines.

Is there a solution/workaround?

Comment: Any one can suggest the solution for this? I'm also facing the same exception

Comment: Currently have the same problem.