# Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Tags: windows-10-universal

I'm facing the exception when click on a textbox which is loaded at runtime. This exception is replicated when all the exception settings are enabled.

Stack Trace:
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The API 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo.get_MetadataToken()' cannot be used on the current platform. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273 for more information.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
  InnerException:

Can anyone help to resolve this?

Comment: I seen you had commented in  [ this thread ] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061249/invalidoperationexception-get-metadatatoken-cannot-be-used-on-the-current-pla). Do you under the same situation?  Are you using SQLite or EF7? In which code line throw this exception? Code please.